# How to fix CFNetwork issue iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, crash, cfnetwork

I have a doubt regarding crashes. In our app, we are getting CFNetwork issues randomly. When we checked the stack trace, we don't have any idea about reproducing. What's the main reason of getting CFNetwork error?

I am using the below third parties:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7.3'
pod 'Branch'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'PPpdf417', '~> 5.1.0'
pod 'JGProgressHUD'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

**Crash 1:**

> Crashed: com.apple.CFNetwork.LoaderQ 0  CFNetwork
>   0x1c14d7f00 HTTPProtocol::shouldAttemptOriginLoad() + 40 1  CFNetwork 
>   0x1c14d7ef4 HTTPProtocol::shouldAttemptOriginLoad() + 28 2  (Missing) 
>   0x748801c14d7a50 (Missing) 3  (Missing)
>   0x6e3e01c1537b0c (Missing) 4  (Missing)
>   0x63a881c15352f0 (Missing) 5  (Missing)
>   0x2f5401c16019e0 (Missing) 6  (Missing)
>   0x4d3981c0808374 (Missing) 7  (Missing)
>   0x4a4901c08098f4 (Missing)

**Crash 2:**

> Crashed: com.apple.CFNetwork.LoaderQ 0  libsystem_kernel.dylib
>   0x1b7ea3104 __pthread_kill + 8 1  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x1b7f23948 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 296 2  libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x1b7dfad78 abort + 140 3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1b7ef7768
>   _malloc_put + 570 4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1b7ef7998 malloc_zone_error + 104 5  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1b7ef7258
>   free_list_checksum_botch + 36 6  libsystem_malloc.dylib
>   0x1b7ef31c4 tiny_free_list_remove_ptr + 488 7  libsystem_malloc.dylib 
>   0x1b7ef3f90 tiny_free_no_lock + 1544 8  libsystem_malloc.dylib
>   0x1b7ef4dc8 free_tiny + 376 9  CoreFoundation
>   0x1b829f978 _CFRelease + 824 10 CFNetwork
>   0x1b8afbe28 HTTPEngine::~HTTPEngine() + 212

**Crash 3:**

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException 0  CoreFoundation
>   0x1b7e13758 __exceptionPreprocess 1  libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x1b701bd00 objc_exception_throw 2  CoreFoundation
>   0x1b7d198b4 -[NSCache init] 3  UIKitCore
>   0x1e46aee48 -[UIPageViewController
>   _validatedViewControllersForTransitionWithViewControllers:animated:] 4  UIKitCore                      0x1e46afa24 -[UIPageViewController
>   _setViewControllers:withCurlOfType:fromLocation:direction:animated:notifyDelegate:completion:]
>   5  UIKitCore                      0x1e46b29f8 -[UIPageViewController
>   _handlePanGesture:] 6  UIKitCore                      0x1e4904608 -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] 7  UIKitCore                      0x1e490cab8
>   _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions 8  UIKitCore                      0x1e490a3b4 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions 9  UIKitCore
>   0x1e4909888 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent

**I can’t able to reproduce the crash? Another way to identify this or Give me an idea to fix this kind of errors ?**

Comment: I see you have no idea what's happening. Neither do (or can) we. Hard to give you any ideas. So let's talk about YOUR code - something you didn''t include and may possibly help. Are you using any third party APIs? Can you do anything to reproduce the code - strip things down, something? - for us to give you some help? If not, how about the opposite? Get your project - or a shell of it - working and then include `CFNetwork. At what point does it break down?

Comment: Can you check my updated answer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/346841#346841

It happens only on iOS12 
And I've found guys using Alamofire/Moya/RxSwift could get this issue

How do you send your request, just Alamofire or Moya?

Comment: Alamofire @Aelam

Comment: @HarikarthickK What do you mean

Comment: I am using Alamofire for sending request.

Comment: @aelam the link is broken. could you share more details?

Comment: @A.K. there are not many links I can find out. I'm glad if you can find more